# mysql-server hangs on setting password

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, mysql, vps

Every time I try install `mysql-server` it hangs on this screen

[image]

This is the case of not entering a password, but when I do enter a password it hangs on this screen after pressing OK

[image]

I've been through a bunch of solutions, namely fully uninstalling and reinstalling and it hasn't worked. The installation was done under the root user.

`syslog`:

```
Jul 30 12:07:25 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:25 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 16893 ...
Jul 30 12:07:25 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:25 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Jul 30 12:07:25 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:25 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
Jul 30 12:07:25 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:25 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Jul 30 12:07:25 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:25 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
Jul 30 12:07:25 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:25 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Jul 30 12:07:25 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:25  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
Jul 30 12:07:25 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
Jul 30 12:07:26 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
Jul 30 12:07:26 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
Jul 30 12:07:27 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
Jul 30 12:07:27 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:28  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:28 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:28 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:28 [ERROR] Aborting
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 
Jul 30 12:07:28 3877-5708-4831 mysqld_safe[16894]: 150730 12:07:28 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

So I'm pretty sure it's InnoDB that's causing the error, but how can I fix the error and make it install without messing up?

Comment: A bit hard to tell anything, but maybe check if there are no remainings from previous installation attempts? For example in /var/lib/mysql. Also check in another terminal if mysql is really running at the time.

Comment: How exactly are you "pressing" the OK button?

Comment: @steeldriver, by pressing enter?

Comment: @Jacek, mysql was completely gone from the system

Comment: Anything under `/var/log/mysql`? Or `/var/log/syslog`? What happens if don't set a password and just hit enter? (It will ask you this several times depending on your installation) What is the command history of your install? Are you also installing `mysql-client`? What happens if you install both side-by-side?

Comment: @eggmatters, Nothing. Added to main post. The first screenshot hangs. Not installing `mysql-client`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by creating `/etc/my.cnf` prior to installing MySQL only containing

```
[mysqld]
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
```

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247633&p=13139456#post13139456)

Comment: That's great you got it up! Can you post a reference to where you discovered this solution?